# Alternative to inheritence for message parsers

Tags: c++, parsing, inheritance, variant, type-erasure

I'm working on 9p protocol parser. Protocol has a bunch of messages. I want to have a simple interface like `auto message = parser.pares(bytesStream);`
What would be the type of `message` in case I want my protocol to be extensible?

Currently I am using `variant<Protocol messages>`. In simple case - where I know all possible version - it is simple. But I'd like to support different protocol versions (extensions: 9p2000.e, 9p2000.u, 9p2000.l, etc) and each can add extra message types. The protocol has a fixed size header Length-Type-Value kind. So I always know message type given a header. But depending on *negotiated* protocol version - type to the messages means slightly different thing.

What are the alternatives to using inheritance when implementing extensible protocol parsers?

That is I need a function of form:

```
parser.parse(header, byteStream) -> Message;
```

The problem here is the type of a message depends on the version.
Normally this can be solved with type inheritance:

```cpp
struct IMessage {}; 
struct p2000::Open : public IMessage {...};
struct p2000e::Open : public IMessage {...};
struct p2000l::Open : public IMessage {...};
```

And parse() -> unique_ptr; // or something like it

The problem is that I'd like to avoid memory-allocations. Thus would like not to use make_unique< p2000l::Open> (...);

Current implementation is just return:

```
parse(...) -> variant<p2000::Open, p2000e::Open, p2000l::Open, ...>;
```

This works ok until I want to have a more modular design of the library. That is when version is negotiated (read a user provided value at runtime) I need to swtich between versions:

```
selectParser(version: String) -> versionedParser;
```

Without storing a `current_version` string the way to do implement - it is to store a jump `table: messgetype ->  *parserFunc`;
That is a table of pointers to a message parser function. Only issue each function return type must be the same. Which means I can't implement them independently from other version. 
That is: `parse_p92000l_open()` must be 'aware' of p92000e message types because the variant return type will have to list all possible message types. Which leaks knowledge about messages from independent protocol version.

So basically I am after better way to express: [Inheritance Is The Base Class of Evil](https://sean-parent.stlab.cc/papers-and-presentations/#inheritance-is-the-base-class-of-evil) concepts.

Anyone solved this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to have a simple interface like

```
auto message = parser.parse(bytesStream);
```

If you return a variant message, all you can really do with it is use visit to handle the contained type.

Since you're doing that anyway, you could instead invert the flow of control so your parser calls a handler (equivalent to the visitor) with the message type it found. Then you don't need a variant or any base class at all.